# Why can't i execute hello world program in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVJpD.png) I have JDK version 10, but when i select a project , I can only see version 9 there. What should I do?

Comment: Looks like you have attached JRE and not JDK ?

Comment: Hover your mouse over red underline to see error message. Click on it and you should be able to copy it. Put error message in your question directly not as image (so others with same problem could actually find this text, since text in images isn't easy for search engines to find).

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question. Your question title and description are totally different.

Comment: Note Eclipse 4.7.3a which has not yet been released is the first Eclipse release with Java 10 support.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you didn't install JRE in Win

You can go to oracle's website to find how to [install the Environment](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GDRAD/java.htm#BGBFJHAB)

You can also install JRE by [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/jdk8)

Another thing is you can use `Alt-Enter` to shortcut to auto import classes.